# Where does internet latency comes from?

Tags: connection, bandwidth, isp, latency, fiber

Sorry if this was asked before. Couldn't find anything about it on SE.

So the distance from San Francisco to Australia is about 8,000 km.

This [source](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) indicates that the latency among the two locations is 183 ms which is similar to what I expect to experience.

But the theoretical latency is 8,000 / (3 * 10^8) = 0.0266 ms. That is distance divided by speed of light.

What causes the rest of the latency? Is that routers? Non fiber connections? High bandwidth? Something else?

Correction: latency = 2 * 8,000,000 / (3 * 10^8) = 52 ms (thanks davidgo) which is not magnitudes away from the 183 ms reported

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-latency

Comment: There are many factors which will play into this, and the factors factors actively effecting, and their levels of effect, change from moment to moment. The latency between two points at a given moment is the sum of all of the factors active at that moment.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things going on here – the main one is your figure for the speed of light is off by 3 orders of magnitude – the figure you quoted is meters per second, not km/second.

The second significant factor is that your ping is a round trip, so 16000 kms, not 8000.

Additionally you have other factors like router latencies and light being in glass/copper, not a vacuum. (The speed through glass is about  2/3 that of a vacuum.)

Comment: There is also retransmission/processing time, when repeaters have to reconstitute the signal in the fiber. And I believe data is often bounced off of satellites.

Comment: @BillDOe Data between LA and Australia with that latency is going over the southern cross cable, which is fibre. Im still getting my head arround the latency descrepency, because I am fairly sure there are no repeaters on the cable, there are things shich amplufy the light signal, which would be MUCH lower latency. Something is still incomplete in my picture, but Ive nor figured it out yet.

Comment: http://www.mapyourtech.com/entries/general/latency-in-fiber-optic-networks has a good breakdown of latency components of a fibre connection.

Comment: Nice link. It's been a while since I've been in the business (telecom), but I do recall that fiber, while being pretty damn clear, still needs signal regeneration.